# Mongoid + RubyMoney

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using RubyMoney (money-rails) https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails with Mongoid. Something like this:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
    field :order_amount, :type => Money, :default => Money.new(0)
    ...
end
```

How can I aggregate on a `Money` field? For example, when I run `Order.sum(:order_amount)`, I get `0` even if the field has a value like `#<Money fractional:5500 currency:USD>`. I've also tried `Order.sum(:order_amount_cents)` and that also returns `0`.

This is the generated Ruby MongoDB command:

```
command={:aggregate=>"orders", :pipeline=>[{"$match"=>{"order_amount"=>{"$nin"=>[nil]}}}, {"$group"=>{"_id"=>"order_amount", "count"=>{"$sum"=>1}, "max"=>{"$max"=>"$order_amount"}, "min"=>{"$min"=>"$order_amount"}, "sum"=>{"$sum"=>"$order_amount"}, "avg"=>{"$avg"=>"$order_amount"}}}]} (2.4292ms)
```

I've also tried using the `moped` aggregate command with `Order.collection.aggregate` and that doesn't seem to work either.

```
Order.collection.aggregate(
    { 
        '$group' => { 
            '_id' => '$order_amount', 
            'totalOrder' => { '$sum' => '$order_amount' }       
        }
    }
)
```

Any help please?

Comment: According to MoneyRails, it's a hash like `#<Money fractional:5500 currency:USD>`. How do I unwrap the hash and aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just addded an answer to this [here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/issues/283)  but just in case someone else comes to this post as I did, I was able to sum money-rails values using something like this:

```
Order.sum("order_amount.cents")
```

This will return just the cents values from the Money-rails structure:

```
{ cents: < value >, currency_iso: < value > }
```

So in order to get the sum in money-rails format you would use:

```
Money.new(Order.sum("order_amount.cents"))
```

Please note that this is when using mongoid v3, because of how money-rails is serialized. 
I believe that with previous versions of mongoid, money-rails objects were serialized using "fractional" instead of cents, so you would have to use:

```
Money.new(Order.sum("order_amount.fractional"))
```

Hope that helps!